# How to create a natural console pause

Tags: c#

How do you make C# do the actual "Press any key to continue" thing? Like when you type `pause` in cmd.

I saw an example once if some special command in C# which did exactly this. I have tried to find it again but every other example on the internet is the obvious `Console.ReadKey();` perhaps with a `Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . .");`

Does anyone know of what I mean?

Comment: What do you want to happen differently compared with the ReadKey solution? Doesn't that work?

Comment: Use Console.ReadLine();

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C pause")` :)

Comment: Press Control + F5 in visual studio. You'll get the magical *Press any key to continue* message once the process completes.

Comment: The purpose is for a more elegant solution. It might have been simply using Control + F5 but don't remember using that. I remember the person even saying how "this is the correct way to do it"

Comment: don't get why console.readkey isn't elegant neither there would be a more correct way

Answer (score 3):

You remember wrong: there is no special command in c# that automatically print the text and wait for input.

Anyway you could write a method:

```
public static void Pause()
{
    Console.Write("Press any key to continue ...");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as [this discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/08163199-0a5d-4057-8aa9-3a0a013800c7/how-to-write-a-command-like-pause-to-console?forum=csharpgeneral) goes, there is no built-in support for that.

You will have to write something similar to this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue...");
Console.ReadKey(true);
```

You can also [import a C function](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/csharp-programming/83394-system-pause-csharp-warning-noob-question.html) if you prefer. The below is citated from that link.

> You have to pinvoke this C function into your C# application. Luckily,
>   this process is very easy. There are a few steps:
>
> 1) Insert System.Runtime.InteropServices to your using clauses. 2)
>   Insert this line in your class (usually in the first few lines)
>
> [DllImport("msvcrt.dll")] static extern bool system(string str);
>
> 3) In that same class, simply write this: system("pause");